# How to disable Windows 10 screen capture

Tags: windows-10

I've enabled screen capture by pressing <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>

Sadly, it didn't do what I wanted, but the application loaded and ran as expected.

Now, when ever I load Chrome, I get told that it is running and I can capture a screen.

I want to disable this. According to https://www.howtogeek.com/273180/how-to-disable-windows-10s-game-dvr-and-game-bar/ I go to Settings and type in gaming, but when I do, I'm informed there are no results.

How do I disable this?

Comment: You have to launch the XBox application to disable Game DVR

Comment: @Ramhound, I didn't actually ever sign into Xbox. Is this really the case, in order to disable that I have to sign in and even create an account?

Comment: You asked how to disable it.  You are either running 1703 without the Media Pack, which means you should install it, then go to the Gaming section or launch the Xbox Application and disable it from within that application.  Checked the linked questions for more information.

Comment: Thank you @Ramhound, yet again your comments have helped me :)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't see "Gaming" in your windows 10 settings app, you're probably running an older version of Win10. In that case, you must go into the **Xbox app** and disable this in its settings as all gaming settings are there.

EDIT: I did some research and there's actually a bug in the Creator's Update where the "Gaming" icon isn't there.

Comment: There isn't a bug.  The people who cannot find the Gaming icon have the N and KN editions of Windows 10 installed.  The Game DVR requires the 1703 Media Pack to be installed before it shows up per the duplicate(s)

Comment: @Ramhound Ah, my bad. If only there weren't as many editions of Windows 10.

Comment: I blame the UN and China for those editions.  Something about user choice being a right.  Same reason Microsoft had to spend hundreds of engineering hours on a browser choice feature.